# Tornar uma transição mais suave

Tags: javascript, css

Gostaria de saber como deixar a transição desta navbar com uma aparência mais suave

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código javascript usado para realiza-la:

```
        var clientHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
        $(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > clientHeight)
                {
                    $('#navigation-bar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                } else {
                    $('#navigation-bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');  
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

A primeira alternativa que me veio na cabeça foi utilizar a propriedade `animation` do `CSS`. Você vai aplicar uma animação a classe `.navbar-fixed-top` para que ela apareça suavemente.

Provavelmente essa classe está atribuindo o `position: fixed;` certo? Você vai precisar adicionar mais duas propriedades:

```
opacity: 0;
animation: navbar .5s linear forwards;
```

E também a animação:

```
@keyframes navbar {
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Fiz um exemplo de como ficará: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ahtoxo7z/)

Talvez tenham outras alternativas, mas só consegui pensar nesta. :P

Comment: É uma boa solução, eu só mudaria o estilo da transição de opacidade para um slide down. Acho que pra menus fica mais suave.